# External Hard Drives not Detected 12.04 LTS

Tags: external-hdd

I have two Western Digital Hard drives that I have been using successfully for months now. A 250gb and a 2tb drive. Now today without any previous issues neither will open from desktop or terminal.

Here is what I found with `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 80.0 GB, 80026361856 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9729 cylinders, total 156301488 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000ceec4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   155387903    77692928   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       155389950   156301311      455681    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       155389952   156301311      455680   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000365289472 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243197 cylinders, total 3906963456 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0005f107

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  3906963455  1953480704    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdc: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x5b6ac646

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1              63   488392064   244196001    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Any help or advice you might have in resolving this would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for not unnecessarily dividing up your partitions, as some do with large hard drives :P

Comment: What exactly do you mean by they "won't open"? Do you receive an error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is detecting the drives. The 2Tb drive is `/dev/sdb` and the 250Gb drive is `/dev/sdc` according to your `fstab -l` above.

What you probably want to do is mount your disks. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB